# Dapper: Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

While using Dapper to call a stored procedure, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Procedure or function has too many arguments specified
```

I'm using DynamicParameters to add a list of simple parameters to the query.

The parameter code looks like this:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add(p.Name, p.Value, direction: p.Mode);
```

The query code looks like this:

```
var result = _connection.Query<T>(
            string.Format("{0}.{1}", request.SchemaName, request.StoredProcedureName),
            parameters,
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            transaction: _transaction);
```

The executing sql in the profiler shows as following:

```
exec dbo.storedProcedureName @ParameterNames1=N'ParameterName',@ParameterNames2=N'ParameterName',@RemoveUnused=1
```

@ParameterNames1 is not at all how the parameter is called. Actually, the names are being passed in as the values (N'ParameterName'). The @RemoveUnused parameter seems completely random to me, as it does not occur in the calling code at all.

The full code for this can be found here: [GitHub project](https://github.com/FlyingPie/Storm/blob/master/Storm.Dapper/DapperSqlExecutor.cs) at lines 61 and 228.

Edit: I've found that the issue is caused by calling the same procedure twice, with different result sets. So the first time I'm calling it with Query, the second time with Query. Why Dapper is having trouble with this scenario is still a mystery.

Comment: Your code seems correct. so now as the error said you have passed some extra parameter which is not defined in your SP. So check your code where you configure your parameter to pass.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: Thank you for your comment. As far as I can see, I don't pass the extra parameter. I've edited the question since I've found some additional information.

Comment: If your SP return multiple results then you can use **QueryMultiple()** of dapper. Rather then calling same SP twice it is better to write SP code such that it execute first result in sp then use it for second result then return these 2 result set as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this issue and this appears to be caused by the following:

- Your stored procedure can return multiple datasets (maybe based on a
  condition parameter).
- You are calling the stored procedure using
  `Query<T>()` instead of `QueryMultiple()` and then mapping datasets
  via `Read<T>`.

We recently upgraded from an old version of Dapper to v1.4 in order to support Table Variable Parameters and we started experiencing this behaviour as a direct result of the upgrade.

**Solution:**

Convert your `Query<T>` based code to a `QueryMultiple` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I simply can't reproduce this:

```
public void SO25069578_DynamicParams_Procs()
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("foo", "bar");
    try { connection.Execute("drop proc SO25069578"); } catch { }
    connection.Execute("create proc SO25069578 @foo nvarchar(max) as select @foo as [X]");
    var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(); // gist used transaction; behaves the same either way, though
    var row = connection.Query<HazX>("SO25069578", parameters,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction: tran).Single();
    tran.Rollback();
    row.X.IsEqualTo("bar");
}
public class HazX
{
    public string X { get; set; }
}
```

works fine. There *is* a `RemoveUnused` property on `DynamicParameters`, bit: when using dynamic parameters, *that shouldn't be added*. I've even tried using the template based constructor:

```
parameters = new DynamicParameters(parameters);
```

but again: this works fine. Is it possible that you're using a *really, really old* version of dapper? What version are you using?

Comment: It seems like a really specific bug then. I'm using the NuGet version, which was 1.27, since the latest came out yesterday. I'll dig into that bit and see if I can find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread. I'm however using the latest version of the Nuget package (1.60.6) and encountered this problem recently.

To reproduce this, you'll need a Stored Procedure that based on an input parameter could return 1 or 2 (more than 1) resultset. In the code, I use 2 different extension methods to call it, too (`QueryMultipleAsync` sets the parameter to 1 or true and `QueryAsync` which sets it to 0 or false). If your test ends up calling the SP to return multiple resultset first, subsequent calls that need 1 resultset will fail with this error.

The only way I managed to solve this was to break down the SP into 2 so they have different names.

For reference, here is how I call the SP:

```
var data = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<T>(
             StoredProcedureName,
             parms,
             transaction: null,
             commandTimeout: null,
             commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

and

```
var data = await sqlConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(
                        StoredProcedureName,
                        param: p,
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                        .Map<Type1, Type2, long>
                        (
                            o1 => o1.Id,
                            o2 => o2.FkId ?? 0,
                            (o1, o2) => { o1.Children = o2.ToList(); }
                        );
```

Answer (score 1):

This Dapper issue is caused by the Read method for reading datasets after a QueryMultiple.
In this case Dapper caches the parameters and if you call the same stored procedure with the same parameters using a Dapper Query method, it will fail.
To solve the problem, change the call to QueryMultiple method from like this:

```cs
var reader = conn.QueryMultiple (spName, pars, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

to this:

```cs
var cmd = new CommandDefinition (spName, pars, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, flags: CommandFlags.NoCache);
var reader = conn.QueryMultiple (cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently hit this problem caused by calling the same procedure twice using different Dapper methods.
The first call to the same SQL stored procedure was via .QueryMultiple.  calling the same procedure with parameters again using .QuerySingleOrDefault resulted in the parameters being ParameterNames1 and RemoveUnused mentioned in the origninal question.